# How to group excel items based on custom rules?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a set of data (webmaster tools search queries) which is in excel with the following header:

`Query | Impressions | Clicks | Date`

Sample google spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B-99bufayQIYsxO2KoN-KmaMHcu8yTCF10g-1ceIMlM/edit#gid=0).

I want to add in an extra column called `Category` and categorize all the queries according to custom rules that will search for a string on column A.
Ex:

`if A2 contains the string 'laptop' then write 'laptop' on the category next to it`

So far I have tried a formula to do this but I'm not sure this is the easiest way. Also, if there are lots of categorization rules the formula gets really long and unmanageable.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("laptop",A2)),"laptop",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("notebook",A2)),"laptop",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("iphone",A2)),"phone",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("galaxy s",A2)),"phone",
"other")))
```

Can you suggest a better way of doing this where I can have the rules in one sheet in this format:

`Query_contains | Category_is`

where `Query_contains` would be the string that needs to be matched in column A from the initial sheet the and `Category` would be the value that needs to be filled into column D.

Comment: `Vlookup` should do EXACTLY what it is you're trying to do... First column would be the value you'd expect in column A and the second column woudl be the category, then you just vlookup to that 2-column table... Let me know if that doesn't make sense....

Comment: @JohnBustos looking at the data in the sample spreadsheet, a simple vlookup won't work.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for that @guitarthrower, I now downloaded the sheet... Posting solution now...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I changed your sheet a bit....

Supposing all your data was in cells A1:C9, then you had the following table in cells F1:G5

```
Search_For:    Category:
laptop         Laptop
iphone         Phone
galaxy         Phone
notebook       Laptop
```

Now, in cell D2, put in the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G$2:G$5,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F$2:F$5,A2)),0)),"other")
```

And **enter it as an array formula** Meaning, once you enter it, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

You can then drag the formula from cell D2 down and it should give you the desired results (and you can, of course, increase the list in columns F & G as necessary).

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: Thanks both of you! - It truly just depends on if you want VBA or formulas... Odds are your soltutions are more efficient, but require VBA... Just depends on which flavor of solution you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks John, your solution worked on Google spreadsheets, but in my Excel 2011 for mac it didn't. I think it's because of the Array formula.. Are you sure it's the same keyword combination on a Mac? `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`? If I press that it wraps curly brackets around the whole formula (including the `=`)

Comment: I don't know on mac, but you should be able to get that right away via google....

Comment: my bad, I had a typo in the formula, that's why it wasn't working. the keyboard shortcut works the same on the mac version, and the curly bracket syntax is ok..

Comment: Would you know if there is a way of incorporating wildcards into this? I have a list of bank transactions and do not want to make a category for each individual purchase. For example, `Card purchase 3393 FOOD` should be categorised as a `card purchase`, but the array above doesn't work if I try to have `Card purchase*` in the `Search_for` column.

Answer (score 3):

This small macro assumes your data is in **Sheet1** and your rules are in worksheet **rules** in columns A & B:

```
Sub catagorize()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim N1 As Long, N2 As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("rules")
    N1 = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    N2 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N1
        v = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = 1 To N2
            If InStr(1, v, s2.Cells(j, 1).Value) > 0 Then
                s1.Cells(i, "D").Value = s2.Cells(j, "B").Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

And for a 3rd option, you could use a custom formula.

I created a table just for categories on a separate sheet, then inserted the following code in a standard module.

```
Option Explicit

Function CategoryLookup(s_Query As String, Keyword_tbl As Range)
    Dim rngKeywords As Range
    Dim s_foundCategory As String
    Dim b_CategoryExists As Boolean
    b_CategoryExists = False

    For Each rngKeywords In Keyword_tbl
        If InStr(s_Query, rngKeywords.Value) <> 0 Then
            s_foundCategory = rngKeywords.Offset(0, 1).Value
            b_CategoryExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rngKeywords

    If b_CategoryExists = True Then
        CategoryLookup = s_foundCategory
    Else
        CategoryLookup = "Other"
    End If
End Function
```

Then in `D2` (your category column) insert the following formula (which can then be dragged down)

```
=CategoryLookup(A2,categories!$A$2:$A$5)
```