# Excel/Categorization Macro(formula) based on string of text containing keywords

Tags: vba, excel

Now I spent a few days searching up and down and need to find a solution.

I saw two threads but both are not what I am looking for exactly and I admit, being not too good in VBA, I cant make heads or tales.

What I have:
I have 4300 lines of Bank statements. There are multiple columns but 1 is of importance - Description. This description might contain a lot of things, but usually there is 1 key word that is crucial. Roughly 96% can be automated and 3-4% just written manually every now and then.

What I want:

A VBA Macro that will read the column description, will match a keyword there from a list of many such in Sheet2, column "keywords" and then write in Column Category (sheet1) the assigned Categorizaion taken from Column Category on Sheet2.

What I have done so far:

the only thing I found to be working for me, and be able to actually reproduce is using a formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("KEYWORD",[Description])),"OUTPUT","")
```

The above formula was repeated multiple times but this slows and lags everything. Besides being unmanagable.

Its working but I need something better. So -> enter Macros. and here I am lost.

I found that the answer of @JohnBustos is very good here:
[How to group excel items based on custom rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993727/how-to-group-excel-items-based-on-custom-rules)
but not working for me really.

I found the answer of  Tomk Dallimore to be what I need or want:
[Categorizing bank transactions in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062929/categorizing-bank-transactions-in-excel?answertab=active#tab-top)

but I cant make heads or tales how to get there??? He is very detailed but I am getting lost on the complexity which mind you is great.

Can you please help me?

I am attaching a very simple example of what I am talking.

http://1drv.ms/1Putpy5

Note#1
I founnd a new formula that I incorporated. 
'=IFERROR(LOOKUP(10^10,SEARCH(" "&KeywordTable[In-keyword]&" "," "&H29& " "),KeywordTable[Out-keyword ]),"")

But this is also troubling the CPU as it calculates each time a cell is moved. I imagine it will throw exception if I add 560 new rows or better yet move the table with 1 poisition. Temporary solution but need something more sophisticated.

*****possibly a terrible idea****
To speed up the macro, such macro as the one you provided in your answer, is it possible to make it work like the automatic date filler macro:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

```html
With Target
            If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            If Not Intersect(Range("B2:B100"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                    .Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
                Else
                    With .Offset(0, 3)
                        .NumberFormat = "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                        .Value = Now
                    End With
                End If
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

Of course, I realize I am asking for something strange but if this can happen it will be rather fast and extremely helpful for optimzing the speed at which the macro is executed for large amounts of data. Now, I have 4500 rows to calculate. Within 2 months, this amount will double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your excel file this code works: 10'000 rows done in 3 secondes with this code.

```
Sub test()

Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim PatternFound As Boolean

Call speedup

lastrow = Sheets("Keywords").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets("SOURCE DATA").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 4 To lastrow2

PatternFound = False

    j = 1

Do While PatternFound = False And j < lastrow

    j = j + 1

            If UCase(Sheets("SOURCE DATA").Range("E" & i).Value) Like "*" & UCase(Sheets("Keywords").Range("A" & j).Value) & "*" Then
                Sheets("SOURCE DATA").Range("F" & i).Value = Sheets("Keywords").Range("B" & j).Value
                PatternFound = True
            End If

  Loop

Next i

Call normal

End Sub

Public Sub speedup()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub

Public Sub normal()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong. Or maybe I explained badly. I entered the code, but it gives conscript out of range.

Comment: I have download your excel file from your cloud and it works perfectly. Be sure of the name of your sheets, is this case is Sheet1 and Patterns

Comment: I edit the code, be sure to put it in a modul and to delete the Public Patterns

Comment: That works perfectly. The only thing I noticed, case sensitivity. Is there a way to make it incensitive?

Comment: I add the fonction UCASE() like this is not case sensitive anymore

Comment: It works. I adapted it to my table but it doesnt answer 1 fundamental question - it works many times slower this way that with the formula, which was the main thing I was trying to avoid. Any ideas there?

Comment: I change the second loop with a Do While loop and add a Boolean. It means when its found it goes directly to the other row. Then I added some spec to speed up the code which took me 2,97 secondes for 10'000 rows. (I use your excel file). Let me know

Comment: It is not executing. When assigning the Macro, I have option Normal and Speedup. Both are not performing the macro. If I run the macro from the VBA Editor, works fine. Where is my noobish head making the mistake sir?

Comment: you just need to run the Sub test() the code will call both Speedup and normal

Comment: I cant seem to find a way to call it. When I create as I was trying a shape to assign the macro on it, I have options Normal and Speedup. I dont see test.

Comment: my bad delete the "Private", just let Sub test()