# VBA - Categorization using "Like"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a Macro to do almost exactly what is outlined here:

[Excel/Categorization Macro(formula) based on string of text containing keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039610/excel-categorization-macroformula-based-on-string-of-text-containing-keywords)

My question is that in the code from the example above Like "" is used to check to see if the Description matches a keyword and if it does then it pulls the corresponding category name. In my case, I don't currently have keywords for every possible category (but will eventually have them as I collect more transaction data), meaning some of the cells in my keyword column are blank and the way the above code is written it considers patternfound = true when it encounters an empty cell. How do I alter the If statement with "Like" or something similar so that it skips over a cell if it's completely blank and only provides a match when there are some characters (that match) in the cell?

I've found a work around by putting "N/A" in the empty cells but I'd rather not do that. Here is my code:

```
Sub Categorize()

Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim PatternFound As Boolean

Call speedup

lastrow = Sheets("Categorization").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets("Cleaned Spend Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 4 To lastrow2

    PatternFound = False

    j = 1

    Do While PatternFound = False And j < lastrow

        j = j + 1

        If UCase(Sheets("Cleaned Spend Data").Range("B" & i).Value) Like "*" & UCase(Sheets("Categorization").Range("B" & j).Value) & "*" Then
            Sheets("Cleaned Spend Data").Range("D" & i).Value = Sheets("Categorization").Range("A" & j).Value
            PatternFound = True
        End If

      Loop

    Next i

    Call normal

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: To add to this - I got around this problem by putting "N/A" in all my blank cells but I'd rather not have to use this work around. Here is my code:

Answer (score 1):

You can test for an empty cell...

Also - your code could be cleaner using a couple of variables for your worksheets.

```
Sub Categorize()

    Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim PatternFound As Boolean, shtCat As Worksheet, shtCleaned As Worksheet
    Dim v, t

    Set shtCat = Sheets("Categorization")
    Set shtCleaned = Sheets("Cleaned Spend Data")

    Call speedup

    lastrow = shtCat.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = shtCleaned.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To lastrow2
        v = UCase(UCase(shtCleaned.Range("B" & i).Value))
        For j = 1 To lastrow
            t = UCase(Sheets("Categorization").Range("B" & j).Value)
            If Len(t) > 0 And v Like "*" & t & "*" Then
                shtCleaned.Range("D" & i).Value = shtCat.Range("A" & j).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Call normal

End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much for your help.